# Reserved Keyword in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Folks,

I wrote a pyspark program which reads json files and converts it into a dataframe. The problem i am facing is when i try to cast and rename a column which happens to be a reserved keywords. The column parent.sub.**GROUP** (group being the reserved word)

Example

```
==> option 1
tempvar2 ="`parent.sub.group`" + ".cast(string).alias(parent_sub_group)"
==> option 2
tempvar2="\"parent.sub.group\"" + ".cast(string).alias(parent_sub_group)"
#pass the variable into select
dataframe2 = dataframe1.select(tempvar2)
```

it is strange that it if i double quote column name it works fine in pyspark shell. if it works in shell it should work with my program as well but i am find it hard to figure out what i am missing. Any help / lead would be appreciated

i have tried the below as well

```
dataframe2= dataframe2.selectExpr("cast (parent.sub.group as string) communities_association_group" )
dataframe2 = dataframe2.selectExpr("cast (\"parent.sub.group\" as string) communities_association_group" )
dataframe2 = dataframe1.selectExpr("cast (\"`parent.sub.group`\" as string) communities_association_group" )
dataframe2 = dataframe2.selectExpr("cast (`parent.sub.group` as string) communities_association_group" )
```

Spark Version : 1.6